# Настройки .htaccess в Laravel, если проект лежит в под папке

Tags: laravel

Я новичок в Laravel. 
В www.example.com есть сайт который разработан не на Laravel. А моя задача была сделать админку на Laravel и положить в папку www.example.com/admin. Админку закончил в Openservere. Но по www.example.com/admin не работает (Error 404). Не могу настроить файл .htaccess.
Вот структура файла:

```html
   RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
    RewriteBase /admin/
```

Answer (score 0):

Пока не получил ответ от вас попробую ответить сам.
Изменил структуру файла вот таким образом.

```html
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com/$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !admin/
RewriteRule (.*) /admin/$1 [L]
```

Но все равно тут приходиться набирать путь полностью : example.com/admin/public. Если не пишешь public, в браузере открывается файловая структура проекта и нажимаешь на папку public вручную. Вот тогда заходит.